# How to get row number in select query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

i try this query to get row number in selected rows, but the output comes like 23,56,78,.... i need to get 1,2,3 to every selected row. please help me

```
SET @row=0;
SELECT `table1`.`col1`,`table1`.`col2`,@row:=@row+1
FROM `table1`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `table2` ON `table1`.`col1` = `table2`.`col5`
WHERE `table2`.`col5` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY `col1` ORDER BY `table1`.`col7` DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: is this something you can do on the front end at all? I've used a temporary table to accomplish this although that may not suit your needs.  MySQL doesn't have a rank function that I know of.

Comment: do you want ordering for your selected rows.

Comment: Why are you using `LEFT JOIN` if you don't want the null rows? Use `INNER JOIN` and those rows won't be in the result in the first place.

Comment: Note that the predicate in the WHERE clause negates "outerness" of the join. The predicate in the join condition guarantees that every "matching" row from `table2` will have a non-null value for `col5`. The only rows that will be excluded by the condition in the WHERE clause would be rows from `table1` that didn't have a matching row in `table2`.

Comment: Is this for `MySQL` or `SQL-Server`? They are not the same.

Comment: because i have empty records in another table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the query with the `ORDER BY` clause into a subquery.

```
SET @row = 0;

SELECT col1, col2, @row := @row+1
FROM (SELECT table1.col1, table1.col2
      FROM table1
      LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.col1 = table2.col5
      WHERE table2.col5 IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY col1
      ORDER BY table1.col7 DESC
      LIMIT 0, 10) AS subquery
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using an inline view. Use a query that gets the rows you want to return, and then wrap that in parens, and reference that query in the `FROM` clause of an outer query.

Something like this:

```
  SELECT v.`col1`
       , v.`col2` 
       , @row := @row + 1 AS `rn`
    FROM ( SELECT `table1`.`col1`
                , `table1`.`col2`
             FROM `table1`
              ... 
            ORDER BY ...
            LIMIT 10
         ) v
```